# php preg_split for languages

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have string like this :

> de:Deutsch-en:English-es:Español-fr:Français-ru:Pусский-jp:日本語

How can I get results with preg_split like this :

> de en es fr ru jp

I did try this:

```
$result = preg_split("/(:(.*)\-)/", "de:Deutsch-en:English-es:Español-fr:Français-ru:Pусский-jp:日本語");
print_r($result);
```

result did come with just first and last match: ﻿﻿

> Array ( [0] => de [1] => jp:日本語 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex

```
:.*?(-|$)
```

should works; try something like:

```
"/:.*?(-|$)/"
```

then:

```
preg_split("/:.+?(-|$)/", "de:Deutsch-en:English-es:Español-fr:Français-ru:Pусский-jp:日本語",-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => de [1] => en [2] => es [3] => fr [4] => ru [5] => jp [6] => ) Last result [6] is empty, maybe we can remove this?

Comment: use the 'PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY' flag.